# Spinner in Android Layout has odd shadow, seems to overlap other components

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am working on android project and I am creating a new layout. The new layout contains a list of EditTexts and a couple of spinners. The EditText components are fine but the spinners have a strange shadow and they seem to overlap the first edit text box and each other and I cannot see why.

Below is my XML layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.BoardiesITSolutions.PasswordManager.AddNewLogin">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Spinner android:id="@+id/cboCategory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/loginType"/>

        <Spinner android:id="@+id/cboLoginType"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/loginType">
        </Spinner>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/login_name"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="URL (http://www.example.com)" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Username" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/password"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is a screenshot showing what I mean

[image: Screenshot showing spinner shadow]

Comment: Please post the layout that you are using for the `Spinners` in the closed state (e.g., the one you are passing into your `Adapter` constructor), along with the code where you are inflating that layout (if you are inflating it yourself).

Comment: As you can see from the XML, I am not dynamically populating the spinners, instead I have a string array which is creating the entries for the spinner. I am not creating my own adapter its all being done through the XML

Comment: I am not aware that the approach that you are taking (`android:entries`) is an especially popular one. You may wish to experiment with `Spinners` where you take greater control over the contents and the inflation process.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm not sure what you mean I am using spinners. `android:entries` is what I've seen from all of the guides, and even if I don't do this and manually create the adapter and populate from a database (therefore not needing the entries) it still has the same style

Comment: "android:entries is what I've seen from all of the guides" -- in contrast, this is probably the third time I have seen `android:entries` used in seven years. "it still has the same style" -- and I can't help you with that, as I cannot see the code that you are using. Suffice it to say that what you have is not what ordinary spinners look like, on any version of Android. They vaguely resemble the old Android 1.x/2.x versions (based on the arrowhead). Perhaps there is an issue with the theme that you are using for this activity.

Comment: I must have been looking at quite an old tutorial, still quite highly ranked on Google so now use `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource()`. Regarding the shadow issue, I've found it, it was what you said, I had a theme being used by the app, which I had a elevation set which for some reason only seemed to affect the spinner. I've removed this and its showing as expected now. Thanks for your help